# operador Like SQL Server siginificado de "-%"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola como les va? Disculpen la molestia.

Bueno quiero consultarles por el uso del caracter **-%** en el operador **Like** de SQL.
La pregunta es que estaria filtrando el **-** y ya que estoy, tambien quiero preguntar que estaria filtrando **-%**

Mi pregunta corresponde a que tengo que mejorar una consulta de seleccion de SQL Server y no logre desifrar que sentido tiene el **-%** en la consulta. Google y siempre me aparece el **Guion bajo** y no el **Menos -**

Les dejo la consulta y sus respectivas tablas por si la quieren chusmear

```
create table facturas(
    Ejercicio varchar(4) not null,
    Numero varchar(9) not null,
    primary key(Ejercicio, Numero),
    Descripcion varchar(100) null,
    IdCliente varchar(4) not null,
    Fecha date null
)

go

create table ItemFactura(
    Ejercicios varchar(4) not null,
    Numeros varchar(9) not null,
    NumeroItem int not null,
    foreign key (Ejercicios, Numeros) references facturas(Ejercicio, Numero),
    primary key(Ejercicios, Numeros, NumeroItem),
    Detalle varchar(100) null,
    Cantidad int not null,
    Monto decimal(30) not null,
)

SELECT F.Numero, F.Ejercicio, I.Monto FROM Facturas F 
JOIN ItemFactura I ON I.Numeros = F.Numero and I.Ejercicios = F.Ejercicio 
WHERE F.Numero LIKE '0000-%' AND F.IdCliente > '0020' AND '0002' = F.Ejercicio
```

Gracias y disculpen las molestias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El guión no es más que un carácter adicional. No es ningún tipo de comodín.

Si nos vamos a la documentación de [like](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), hay una tabla con los caráter comodín.

| Carácter | Descripción | Ejemplo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| % | Cualquier cadena de cero o más caracteres | WHERE title LIKE '%computer%' |
| _ | Cualquier carácter individual | WHERE au_fname LIKE ‘_ean’ |
| [] | Cualquier carácter individual del intervalo ([a-f]) o del conjunto ([abcdef]) que se ha especificado. | WHERE au_lname LIKE ‘[C-P]arsen’ |
| [^] | Cualquier carácter individual que no se encuentre en el intervalo | WHERE au_lname LIKE ‘de[^l]%’ |

Por tanto, la búsqueda de `0000-`, es lo mismo que buscar 0000- y nada más que esa cadena.

| cadena | resultado | patrón |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0000-1ab | true | '0000-%' |
| 0000-2ab | true | '0000-%' |
| 0001-3ab | false | '0000-%' |
| 0000 1ab | false | '0000-%' |
| 0000-1ab | true | '0000_%' |
| 0000-2ab | true | '0000_%' |
| 0001-3ab | true | '0000_%' |
| 0000 1ab | true | '0000_%' |
| 0000 1ab | false | '0000_' |

En conclusión, `-` es un carácter más. Por tanto esa búsqueda de cuatro ceros y un guión. Busca explicitamente cuatro ceros y un guión, y luego lo que venga después.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias Javi, yo pensaba que el guion bajo y el guion medio eran distintos, perfecto muchas gracias y disculpa las molestias.

Comment: El guion bajo y el guion medio son distintos. El guion bajo sirve como comodín de un caracter individual, mientras que el guion medio solo se representa a si mismo.